# Google Places Api is picking up wrong address or wrong location

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have just started to use google places api. When I put in the address of 2669 Davis Blvd, Naples Fl, its shows me the correct address on the drop down but when I pickup the address its populating 2669 Naples Cir, SomeOtherCityInFlorida, Florida

I used to be using google's geocode. However I have noticed that in the last 2-3 days, its not recognizing certain street names but recognizes the Route numbers: Example 2669 Davis Blvd, Naples Florida wouldnt be recognized but 2669 Route 84 Naples OR 2669 Hwy 84, Naples would pickup the location correction

Has anyone else faced this problem in the last few days (May 13th 2013)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Just submitted a bug to the Places API issue tracker, here: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6666&thanks=6666&ts=1399400982

Answer (score 1):

Finding the same thing here.  A lot of previously correct addresses are now not Geo-coding.
Had mixed results using different devices / apps.  Seems to work sometimes but not others.  The auto complete seems to still be working as it should but any details requests on certain places will fail.